# Case sensitivity issue on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dblink

I have a Dblink in place between my Oracle database and Microsoft SQL Server, fetching data from SQL server while on Oracle. Connectivity is fine but I am getting invalid column names whenever I try to include any column name in my select query.

On Oracle with Dblink:

```sql
select COLUMN1 from table1@dblink
```

Fails with:

> ORA-00904: COLUMN1: invalid identifier

On Oracle with Dblink, this works fine.

```sql
select "COLUMN1" from table1@dblink
```

On SQL server this works fine:

```sql
select column1,COLUMN1 from table1
```

Seems case sensitivity is not enforced when on SQLserver, however, while trying from oracle it is enforced, any idea how I can bypass this,

The collation on my SQL server is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: `"COLUMN1"` is the same as `column1` or `COLUMN1` in Oracle, so it looks quite strange. Can you please share an output of both (working and not) queries that were executed via SQL*Plus (or F5 in SQL Developer).

Comment: Thanks @astentx. Please see below output  

working
Presentm
--------
02092022
02092022

Not working

Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 74
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PRESENTMENTDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I mean execute two scripts with `set echo on` to see the actual query. In case of Oracle at the remote side you may use `all_tab_cols@dblink`, but for SQL Server it should be different

Comment: And the same for working query